# how to pagination when using file_put_contents in php

Tags: php, html, pagination

I am new to this forum.I just want to ask you how to paginate to different pages of a website using loop.here i am using this code to achieve my result, but failed to move to the next page of the website

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.pakwheels.com/used-cars/search/-/?page=2');

$file = 'pakwheels.txt';

file_put_contents($file , $html, FILE_APPEND);
```

As you can see the link look like this but how to increment the page number when page 2 result is stored in a file.

Comment: Have you tried writing the loop? If yes, what problems did you ran into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

haven't tested this code, but it should point you in the right direction. this will loop 5 times, starting with page 1, and ending with page 5, while creating new text files for each loop iteration.

```
<?php 
for ($x = 1; $x <= 5; $x++) {
    $html = file_get_contents('http://www.pakwheels.com/used-cars/search/-/?page=' . $x . '');

   $file = 'pakwheels-' . $x . '.txt';

   file_put_contents($file , $html, FILE_APPEND);
} 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks stoopkid1. I will try and respond back to all of you.

Comment: thanks stoopkid1 its working perfectly, but i have made some addition to this code for file creation,because you are creating new files for the loops and i want the same file with this code.

Comment: Lastly bro, When I execute this code for page number 1924 . it is showing me error that maximum execution time is 60 sec. can you tell me an alternate way to achieve this . What you say about clonejobs. will i achieve this with clonejobs in web hosting.

Comment: the max execution error is referencing a php.ini setting from your hosting provider. if you are able to modify the php.ini file, there is a setting for "max_execution_time" which you would need to change. if you can't change that setting, i suggest running your script in batches, instead of all 1900+ pages.

Comment: what you say about cronjob in webhosting

Comment: I am making a web crawler that's why ?

Comment: Brother how to find the total number of pages in a website and pass it in a for loop to run dynamically

Comment: @SyedKäshäñÑïzâmî you are getting off topic from the original question, so please start a new question thread. remember, this site is for getting help with code you have written. do not expect other people to do the work for you.

Comment: sorry man. they said I have to wait for 4 days to ask a new question